# How to keep database data when run py.test?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I want to test my query db function.

```
import pytest
from account_system.action import my_action
from account_system.models import MyUser

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_ok_profile():
    req = FakeRequest()
    email = 'tester@example.com'
    MyUser.objects.create_user(
        email=email,
        password="example",
    )
    # query MyUser table and return result
    result = my_action.get_profile(email)
    assert result == 'success'
```

But it's fail.

```
>       assert result == 'success'
E       assert None == 'success'
```

The function doesn't get any result from DB.

I check the database data and doesn't see any record.
(ex. User *tester@example.com*)

**How to rewrite my code for testing?**

Or **how to keep data in database?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of how databases tests works.. 
When you set a django_db, the pytest will rollback your data after use.
But if you want to use the same data in several tests, you should take a look on 
pytest.fixtures and factory_boy like :

```
import factory

class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

@pytest.fixture
def user():
  return UserFactory(email = "bla@bla.com", password = "blabla")
```

And now you apply this reference on your test code:

```
test_test_ok_profile(user):
  assert user.email = "bla@bla.com"
```